# Работа с указателями и со строками СИ

Tags: c++, указатели

Мне непонятно, почему, например, для вывода указателя на int, его сначала нужно разыменовать, а при использовании указателя на char для вывода строки, операция разыменовывания уже не требуется, оно и так всё красиво выводит.

```
int* a = new int[5];

// Здесь будет выводиться адрес памяти.
cout << a << endl;

char* c = new char[4];

strcpy(c, "sasa");

// А вот здесь уже находится сама строка
// хотя, я думал, что здесь должен был бы выводиться адрес первого символа строки.
cout << c;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень много индивидуальных определений оператора `<<`. Для строк сделали вывод строки, а для других указателей как указатель.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator<</](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

```
single character (1)    
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, char c);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, signed char c);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, unsigned char c);
character sequence (2)  
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const signed char* s);
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const unsigned char* s);
rvalue insertion (3)    
template<class charT, class traits, class T>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>&
  operator<< (basic_ostream<charT,traits>&& os, const T& val);

arithmetic types (1)    
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (long long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
stream buffers (2)  
ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );
manipulators (3)    
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что оператор `<<`  для `std::cout` перекрыт для множества типов. Для `char*` он обучен тому, чтобы при выводить C-строку по данному адресу.

Хотите адрес - приведите к `void*`